Behavior-Tree navigator not recognizing a basic condition node
I followed the BT Plugin tutorial (https://docs.nav2.org/plugin_tutorials/docs/writing_new_bt_plugin.html)
in order to create this simple C++ BT Condition Node:

#include "nav2_behavior_tree/plugins/control/portenta_control.hpp"
#include <bitset>

namespace nav2_behavior_tree
{

PortentaControl::PortentaControl(const std::string & name)
: BT::ControlNode::ControlNode(name, {}), status_(0)
{
  node_ = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("portenta_control_node");
  subscription_ = node_->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Int32>(
    "/portentastatus", 10,
    std::bind(&PortentaControl::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
  RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "PortentaControl node initialized");
}

PortentaControl::PortentaControl(
  const std::string & name,
  const BT::NodeConfiguration & config)
: BT::ControlNode(name, config), status_(0)
{
  node_ = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("portenta_control_node");
  subscription_ = node_->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Int32>(
    "/portentastatus", 10,
    std::bind(&PortentaControl::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
  RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "PortentaControl node initialized with config");
}

BT::PortsList PortentaControl::providedPorts()
{
  return { BT::OutputPort<int>("status") };
}

BT::NodeStatus PortentaControl::tick()
{
  //const auto num_children = children_nodes_.size();

  // Spin the node to process subscriptions
  rclcpp::spin_some(node_);

  setStatus(BT::NodeStatus::RUNNING);

  // Check if bit 0 is set and bit 1 is not set
  if ((status_ & 0b0001) == 1 && (status_ & 0b0010) >> 1 == 0) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "Bit 0 is set and bit 1 is not set. Waiting, status_: %s", std::bitset<32>(status_).to_string().c_str());
    while ((status_ & 0b0001) == 1 && (status_ & 0b0010) >> 1 == 0) {
      rclcpp::spin_some(node_);  // Ensure to spin the node to process the subscription callback
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
  }

  // Check if bit 1 is set or bit 0 is not set
  if ((status_ & 0b0010) >> 1 == 1 || (status_ & 0b0001) == 0) {
    ControlNode::haltChildren();
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "PortentaControl node return SUCCESS (Bit 1 is true or Bit 0 is false), status_: %s", std::bitset<32>(status_).to_string().c_str());
    return BT::NodeStatus::SUCCESS;
  }

  return BT::NodeStatus::RUNNING;
}

void PortentaControl::halt()
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "Halting PortentaControl");
  ControlNode::halt();
  status_ = 0;
}

void PortentaControl::callback(const std_msgs::msg::Int32::SharedPtr msg)
{
  status_ = msg->data;
  RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "Received new status: %d, status_: %s", status_, std::bitset<32>(status_).to_string().c_str());
}

}  // namespace nav2_behavior_tree

#include "behaviortree_cpp_v3/bt_factory.h"
BT_REGISTER_NODES(factory)
{
  factory.registerNodeType<nav2_behavior_tree::PortentaControl>("PortentaControl");
}


And added it (PortentaControl XML tag) to my XML BT file:

<root main_tree_to_execute="MainTree">
  <BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">
    < MORE .....>
                <Sequence>
                  <PortentaControl/>
    < MUCH MORE ...>              
</root>


Also I added the library name in the nav2_params.yaml file (bt-navigator section) :

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      ( MANY OTHERS ...)
      - portenta_control


When I launch the Navigation2 system I get the following errors:

ERROR loading library [libportenta_control.so]: can't find symbol [BT_RegisterNodesFromPlugin]
[bt_navigator]: Exception when loading BT: Error at line 47: -> Node not recognized: PortentaControl


Does somebody know what am I missing? Thanks!
EDIT: problem was a bad library generation caused by a bad macro definition (BT_REGISTER_NODES), solved it following this article:
https://blog.csdn.net/zvvzxzko2006/article/details/109854537

Few that things that come to my mind and that I encountered, and I check when I meet that error:

Be sure to have sourced your environment after (first) compilation
Be sure to recompile the package containing the nav2_params.yaml
Check that the name of the lib in your CMakeList.txt is correct ("portenta_control")
That the plugin is correctly installed in the CMakeList (cf. 'ament_export_libraries' and 'install' directives)


Hi! What do you mean by recompiling the nav2 package? The plug in libraries are loaded by BT-Navigator on runtime from the yaml list, no recompile needed. Is it necessary to build from source the full nav2 stack? Can't it be done using normal installation on /opt/ros/humble via apt-get install?

Besides, I know the library is correctly loaded because first times, I got the "Library not found error" but copying the lib.so file into /opt/ros/humble/lib solved it and now it gives me the "Node not recognized" error

No need to recompile the full Nav2 stack :)
I meant to run 'colcon build --packages-select , because depending your setup/launch config, this file may be search in the /install dir instead of the /src dir (bu depends on your config)

Maybe a snippet of your CMakeLits.txt would help ? (on my side I put my custom BT nodes in a dedicated package, to keep them separated from nv2 code)

I cannot compile any package containing nav2_params.yaml, because that package is nav2_bringup and I don't have any Nav2 package, source code or workspace, but only the installation on /opt/ros/humble/share. I insist in the fact that re-compiling the nav2_params package isn't needed as the BT-Navigator is finding and loading the library on runtime. And that is working good.
I solved it reading this: https://blog.csdn.net/zvvzxzko2006/article/details/109854537
